# SQOOP Import : remove pilcrow in ORACLE CLOB data type

Tags: sql, oracle, sqoop

I am importing ORACLE tables to Hive (Hadoop) with sqoop.
But some fields in ORACLE tables are CLOB type with "pilcrow"(¶).
I would like to remove these "pilcrows" (paragraph symbol).
Does anyone have the method to do this directly in the sqoop command or in sql?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I had a similar issue in the past with a different ASCII extended character. The best approach for me was to create a function to replace those characters in a clob string and invoke the function in the select statement you use in sqoop, or create a view with the select using the function and then run sqoop over the view. If you are interested, I can provide an example of the clob function

Comment: @RobertoHernandez, if you can do it (provide that function or an example), I'll appreciate.
thanks.

Comment: I post my answer. I'd appreciate if you upvote it . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you in the comments, let me show you one way to achieve this by using a function in Oracle to replace any character in a CLOB field

On my Demo below I use Oracle 12cR2 with AL32UTF8 as characterset.

```
SQL> create table dptos ( c1 number , c2 number , c3 clob );

Table created.

SQL> insert into dptos values ( 1 , 1, 'Clob Example with Ascii extended character € here' );

1 row created.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from dptos ;

        C1         C2
---------- ----------
C3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1          1
Clob Example with Ascii extended character € here
```

My function replaces the pattern ( which could be a character or an ascii function ) by another string or nothing

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CLOBREPLACE (p_input       CLOB
                      , p_pattern     VARCHAR2
                      , p_substitute  CLOB)
   RETURN CLOB
   IS
      C_MAXLEN   CONSTANT NUMBER  := 32000;
      v_fclob             CLOB    := p_input;
      v_foffset           INTEGER;
      v_fchunk            CLOB;
   BEGIN
      IF LENGTH (p_substitute) > C_MAXLEN
      THEN
        v_foffset := 1;
        v_fclob   := REPLACE (v_fclob, p_pattern, '###CLOBREPLACE###');
        <<replace_by_loop>>
        WHILE v_foffset <= LENGTH (p_substitute)
        LOOP
           v_fchunk :=
              SUBSTR (p_substitute, v_foffset, C_MAXLEN)
              || '###CLOBREPLACE###';
           v_fclob := REGEXP_REPLACE (v_fclob, '###CLOBREPLACE###', v_fchunk);
           v_foffset := v_foffset + C_MAXLEN;
        END LOOP replace_by_loop;
        v_fclob := REGEXP_REPLACE (v_fclob, '###CLOBREPLACE###', '');
      ELSE
         v_fclob := REPLACE (v_fclob, p_pattern, p_substitute);
      END IF;
      RETURN v_fclob;
END clobreplace;
/
```

Let's check it

```
SQL> select c1 , c2, clobreplace ( c3 , '€' , 'Euros' ) from dptos ;

        C1         C2
---------- ----------
CLOBREPLACE(C3,'€','EUROS')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1          1
Clob Example with Ascii extended character Euros here
```

If you have problems invoking the function from sqoop, you can always create a view with the select and then run sqoop over the view.